# Git repository from one machine to another

Tags: git

So I have a git repository that i pulled at one point and that repository resides on a server.  I don't have access to the original repository that I pulled it from.  How do i get the code from the existing server to another computer?

EDIT 1:
So here's what it looks like:

- COMPUTER A:  The git repository that I originally checked out from.  I don't have access to this anymore.
- COMPUTER B: A shared server that I have the code checked out on.
- COMPUTER C: A Local laptop.

Can i just do a simple copy of that directory without using git, or can I use git to clone if from B to C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either pull from the network location or copy the entire directory(containing .git folder) accross to the other computer.

Answer (score 35):

This is achieved by creating a clone of the repository that is on COMPUTER B, by running the command `git clone` on COMPUTER C, where you want the cloned repository to be created. Cloning in git can be done using multiple protocols, including ssh, https, git; and these require an appropriate setup for the `git clone` command to succeed.

The easiest approach is to start the git server on COMPUTER B using this command:

```
> git daemon
```

For help with the above command, run `git help daemon`

Then place a marker file in the .git folder of the repository on COMPUTER B to grant permission to the git server to run the clone command on that repository. This is done by:

```
> cd <repository root>/.git
> touch git-daemon-export-ok
```

Now, from a terminal on COMPUTER C, run the following commands:

```
> cd <folder in which to create the cloned repository>
> git clone git://<ip address of COMPUTER B>/<full path of the repository on COMPUTER B>
```

This will create the cloned repository on COMPUTER C.

Comment: It gives error: access denied or repository not exported.

Comment: I got 'connection refused' how can I setup git pemission in git repos?

Answer (score 3):

You can just clone it from the server, assuming you have access to where the clone is stored - the power of distribution ;)

Comment: I'm not sure i have access to where the clone is stored.  Not sure how i pulled the original code set either.

Comment: I think Matt means to clone it to from compuer B ("existing server") to computer C ("another computer"). Computer A is the one you don't have access to anymore. git clone entry in manual: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html

Comment: Do you have a clone on your computer locally then? You can clone from that just the same; the repositories contain all of the same information, modulo any changes since you last pulled.

Comment: I don't have a clone on my computer locally no.  Just on the original workstation that i originally pulled the code to.

Let me edit the question with more information.

Comment: Yeah, based on your edit, you can clone from computer B to C, like @matt b said. That's what's meant by "distributed source control" - there's no difference between cloning from B or from A onto C, and its just as easy to add A as a remote to C later if you get access back and want to make that the 'main' upstream repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can run from computer C:

```
git clone username@computer_B:path/to/root/of/repository
```

assuming that computer B has a ssh server running.
Otherwise other protocols are supported (file://, http://, \\computer_B (NetBios), ...)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has any issues with cloning, I used simply this, on the machine you want app to be cloned to:

1. in CMD go to folder where you want your app to be cloned to, for example `cd C:/my_apps/`
2. login to github and go to app you want to clone, press green button "Clone or Download", you will see SSH link, copy it.
3. in CMD run `git clone git@github.com:user/my-app.git` (use SSH link you copied)

Done

Answer (score 1):

You mean you wanna clone it to a different computer?

How about:

```
git clone ssh://myserver/path/to/myproject.git
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand the question right, you just want to transfer the history of code from B to C. Actually because git uses de-centric model, B has complete history of the code till the last sync point between B and A.

I can think of three methods if you just want to transfer code history from B to C:

- direct copy/rsync/etc. just copy all files and structures in \B-machine\code.git to \C
- git clone: this is best choice if C can access B through http or ssh
- git bundle: git supports bundle command, and after bundle, you copy/rsync/ftp/scp bundle file to C