# GitHub and Android studio no gradle.build

Tags: java, android, git, github

So I created an Android studio project, then trough it I created a Git repository and published it.

Now I'm on a different computer trying to sync it all. So from the home of android studio I select "Check out project from Version Control" then Git, paste the github repo link and it imports the code, but no all.

When I open the imported project the Gradle Script is missing (tough it's not shown even in the GitHub repo), the manifest folder and to show the res folder i have to change the type under 1:project to "project". 
If I open an activity xml file it won't give the option to switch between Design and Text. And it doens't recognise some component like "AppCompactActivity" in the java files.

Anyone knows what is happening and how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: [Check this link.it might help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090809/git-repository-from-one-machine-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't commit all files. Also you should check that the IDE is the same on both computer, same gradle plugin, same Android Studio version and so on.

Check that your gradle exist on your github repo in remote